widget position always get messed up in other laptop
I know a lot of people already ask this thing and I already follow their answer but it still does not fix my issue.
So I made GUI using kivy, but every time I open the GUI in a different laptop, the widget position always gets messed up. Is it because the difference of the laptop screen size? My friends has a smaller screen size than me. The widget position in kivy is in the percentage of the screen or the parent widget, is it why the widget position always get messed up in other laptop that have different screen size than me (especially laptop that has smaller screen size)?
So, because of that, I think setting a fix non-resizable window size would probably help.
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set ("graphics", "resizable", False)
Config.set ("graphics", "width", 1920)
Config.set ("graphics", "height", 1080)

I already set the resizeable as false and set my window width and height in a fix size, but why when I start my application it's still start as minimize (?) like it's not picking up the size that I already set.
And I already set the resizeable as False, but it only turn off the corner resizable off, I want it to be a fix size and non-resizable whether from right, left, or corner. Is that possible to do?
I actually want my application to be on full screen, that's why I set it to 1920 x 1080. And I want it also be full screen on my others friends laptop too. I tried to set it to always be open as maximize, but it's still messed the widget positon in other laptop that is bigger/smaller than mine.
note :
my laptop screen size it's pretty big than the laptop that my peers usually have (my laptop have the numpad keyboard, meanwhile most of my friends laptop don't)
